# Jaw Master Rig Diagonal

Tags: rigging

[image]
Hi, my jaw master rig is at an angle for some reason. I have attached a picture with the meta rig where everything appears to be normal
[image]

Comment: check the bone roll, and check the object you used for the bone shape, make sure is centered in the origin, and not unproperly rotated...

Comment: Ive tried bone roll, along global x,y and z and applied transform and its had no effect. It still stays in its original position

Comment: try to clear the pose rotation in pose mode...

Comment: Where do I go to do that?

Comment: go to pose mode and select all bones and then alt+r , alt+g , alt+s...if didnt work then i dunno

Comment: It worked! Thanks!